# Is a new thread created while reading and writing from gorrila websocket?

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

```
import (

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

var conn  *websocket.Conn

/// Initializing the socket
...

_, bytes, err := conn.ReadMessage()
```

How does the ReadMessage work? Does it create a new thread to listen on it's socket? Or does it keep waiting to receive message?

I have the same doubt for  `conn.WriteMessage`

Comment: See https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/websocket#hdr-Concurrency

Answer (score 0):

The Gorilla websocket package does not create goroutines.

ReadMessage reads the next message from the underlying network connection and returns that message when done.

WriteMessage writes a message to the underlying network connection and returns when done.